# wysiwyg + ckeditor - failed to open stream sites/default/files/js/wysiwyg/wysiwyg_ckeditor_XXX.js

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using [WYSiWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) with CK editor. I am getting this error whenever i am trying to access a form with ckeditor.

> file_get_contents(MYSITE/sites/default/files/js/wysiwyg/wysiwyg_ckeditor_lMF9rzHK588_LcHaW11FHc_RkSCpdKrS7MgWsyqXXEM.js)
>
> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed!
>
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 4846 of
>   /var/www/html/dev3/wifh/includes/common.inc).

This file "wysiwyg_ckeditor_lMF9rzHK588_LcHaW11FHc_RkSCpdKrS7MgWsyqXXEM.js" exist with content

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/MYSITE/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/';
```

Answer (score 2):

This bug should be fixed in the latest dev snapshot of wysiwyg:

See also http://drupal.org/node/1802394 (which essentially provides a patch for the previous response above).

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit `wysiwyg.module` file
2. Find this `drupal_add_js(file_create_url($uri), $default_library_options)`;`
3. Replace with this `drupal_add_js($uri, $default_library_options);`

Comment: Definitely the solution but more explanations are welcome.

Comment: please do not hack core or contrib modules..